# Processing error message 'The function getJSONArray(JSONArray) does not exist'

Tags: arrays, json, httpclient, processing

i am not sure why i am getting the error message **'The function getJSONArray(JSONArray) does not exist'** when i run this sketch that uses a json query to Weather Underground. That comment seems illogical since Processing is recognising the id ref for the JSONArray.

The .json can be read here: http://api.wunderground.com/api/97a2805510de59e9/hourly/q/pws:IENGLAND274.json

Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
import com.francisli.processing.http.*;

HttpClient client;
String data;
com.francisli.processing.http.JSONObject weatherInfo;

JSONArray hourly_forecast;

int last = 0;
PImage img;
Float humidity = 50.2;



void setup() {
  size(700, 700);

  client = new HttpClient(this, "api.wunderground.com");

  client.GET("/api/97a2805510de59e9/hourly/q/pws:IENGLAND274.json");

  background(255);
}

void responseReceived(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {

  println(response.getContentAsString());

  weatherInfo = response.getContentAsJSONObject();

  JSONArray hourly_forecast = weatherInfo.getJSONArray(hourly_forecast);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called `getJSONArray()` that takes in a JSONArray as an argument.

The function should be used as `JSONArray.getJSONArray(0)` which gets the first array of elements in your JSON data. You can put this in a loop to get all of them.

Example (taken from: http://art.buffalo.edu/coursenotes/art380/reference/JSONArray_getJSONArray_.html):

```
// The following short JSON file called "data.json" is parsed 
// in the code below. It must be in the project's "data" folder.
//
// [
//   [
//     { "name": "apple", "isFruit": true },
//     { "name": "grape", "isFruit": true },
//     { "name": "carrot", "isFruit": false }
//   ],
//   [
//     { "name": "lettuce", "isFruit": false },
//     { "name": "plum", "isFruit": true },
//     { "name": "cinnamon", "isFruit": false }
//   ]
// ]

JSONArray json;

void setup() {

  json = loadJSONArray("data.json");

  // Get the first array of elements
  JSONArray values = json.getJSONArray(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

    JSONObject item = values.getJSONObject(i); 

    String name = item.getString("name");
    boolean isFruit = item.getBoolean("isFruit");

    println(name + ", " + isFruit);
  }
}

// Sketch prints:
// apple, true
// grape, true
// carrot, false
```

Second problem with your code is that you're declaring hourly_forecast twice: once globally and once within the `responseReceived()` function. You probably want to remove `JSONArray` from `hourly_forecast` within the `responseReceived()` function.

Comment: As the file I am loading is a JSONObject containing various JSONArray objects, how do you suggest I 'grab' the JSONArray items?